# How to use Intel Hardware Assisted Virtualization on Ubuntu to emulate Android phones with Android Studio

Tags: intel, kvm-virtualization, android-studio, qt5, android-emulator

I have been trying to install and use KVM on Ubuntu 16.04 for emulating Android phones which run the apps I build with Android Studio. For some reason launching the emulator on Ubuntu seems to be a lot more complex than on Windows; maybe I am not seeing something but on Windows all I have to do is to download Android Studio and install Intel HAXM. But on Ubuntu I need to install KVM and other software. I started with following [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator) link and I ran into issues with the emulator not finding Qt.5.7; here are the exact messages:

```
@:~/Android/Sdk$ ./emulator/emulator64-x86 -avd Nexus -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm
./emulator/emulator64-x86: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.7' not found (required by ./emulator/emulator64-x86)
./emulator/emulator64-x86: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by ./emulator/emulator64-x86)
./emulator/emulator64-x86: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by ./emulator/emulator64-x86)
./emulator/emulator64-x86: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by ./emulator/emulator64-x86)
./emulator/emulator64-x86: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Svg.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by ./emulator/emulator64-x86)
```

So I installed Qt at

```
/home/sansari/Qt5.7.0
```

And set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sansari/Qt5.7.0/Tools/QtCreator/lib
$ printenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/sansari/Qt5.7.0/Tools/QtCreator/lib
```

I have also tried

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sansari/Qt5.7.0/Tools/QtCreator/lib/
```

But I still see the original error about the emulator not finding Qt_5.7. How can I fix this please? I did notice that the earlier versions of Qt are in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` Does that have anything to do with my error?

Update: I just tried the following command and it seems like the new Qt install did not propogate through my system. Would this help figure out what might be the issue and the fix?

```
qmake -version
```

QMake version 3.0

```
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: I have no idea but I suspect it is because you are not using apt to install android studio - https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-android-studio-ubuntu-16-04 . You running qt for android ? How did you install ASK ?

Comment: I followed https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu to install Qt. I appreciate the link, and will give it a try. Is KVM the only option for emulating Android phones on Ubuntu? How come Intel provides haxm for Windows, but on Ubuntu we have to use KVM? I am just trying to see if I am making things difficult for myself. Do you think the apt package would just run an emulator for me? Given that I have 500G more on my HD, I can just install the Android Studio package, and then delete the other one if everything goes well.

Comment: Wow that is a really old tutorial. I guess it depend on what you are trying to do exactly. In general you want to use apt-get as much as possible and you may need to install 32 bit libs.

Comment: Ok, the items which work fine are Android Studio, which lets me create an app and push it a phone. But I am stuck on the emulator. Is there a way to push this discussion to the stackoverflow, and see what the developers have to say about it since Android Studio is a development tool?

Comment: Just ask there. You need to describe at what point you are getting stuck. The short answers to some of your question is 1. You would have to ask Intel about their software. On Linux KVM/QEMU is well established , VirtualBox is in some ways a fork of QEMU. The android emulators are slow, at least the ones i have run, and KVM/QEMU is probably the best solution on Linux right now.